# How to pass parameter to react native redux action?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am creating an application using redux. So I have created a store. Store also uses the `redux-thunk`. Then I have also reducer which manipulate the state and the actions for reducers.

Now, I have an action called `doAuth.js` in which I want to just authenticate the user. But I am not able to pass email and password from my `Login.js` container.

Here is what I have done so far :

In my `Login.js`, I added below two functions and connected component to store :

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        authentication: state.authentication
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    doAuth: (email, password) => dispatch(doAuth(email, password))
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Login);
```

And I am calling the action from the button as following :

```html
<MButton 
    text="LOGIN" 
    onPress={() => this.props.dispatch(doAuth(this.state.email, this.state.password))}
/>
```

In above `this.state.email` and `this.state.password` contains the email and password from `Textinput`.

Here is my action **doAuth.js** :

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import * as Types from '../constants';
import Api from '../../config/Api';

const doAuth = (email, password) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type:Types.AUTHENTICATING
        });
        alert(JSON.stringify(email)); // It just alert "[object object]"
        alert(JSON.stringify(email)); // It gives me error "json.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures react native"  
        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': Api.token
        }
        const data = {
            "email": "test@gmail.com",
            "password": "123456"
        }
        axios.post(`${Api.url}/login`, data, {headers}).then((response) => {
            dispatch({
                type: Types.USER_FOUND,
                data: response
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            dispatch({
                type:Types.AUTH_ERROR,
                error
            });
        });

    }

}

export default doAuth
```

I also tried to passing `mapDispatchToProps` to connect as below but not working :

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

**Updated**

Here is how I set email and password :

```html
<InputBox
    label="Email Address"
    placeholder="Type Here"
    returnKeyType={"next"}
    autoFocus={true}
    value={this.state.email}
    onChange={(email) => this.setState({email})}
/>
<InputBox
    label="Password"
    placeholder="Type Here"
    textContentType="password"
    secureTextEntry={true}
    value={this.state.password}
    onChange={(password) => this.setState({password})}
/>
```

`InputBox` is custom component with `TextInput` with some extra styles.

So please, anyone can help me how can I pass my email and password to action so I can authenticate using API.

Comment: like `this.props.doAuth('g@gmail.com', 'dfdr&8')`;

Comment: @JuniusL. I tried but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call an mapped dispatch with `this.props.dispatch(...)`, just call `this.props.mappedDispatch(...)`.

```
<MButton 
    text="LOGIN" 
    onPress={() => this.props.doAuth(this.state.email, this.state.password)}
/>
```

**Edit:** Change `export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Login)` to `export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login)`. You are passing `null` as the second argument to `connect()`

**Edit 2:** The `onChange={...}` prop should be replaced with `onChangeText={...}` in `InputBox` component.

Comment: Thank for your answer but it gives me error `"_this.props.doAuth is not a function. (In '_this.props.doAuth(_this.state.email, _this.state.password)', '_this.props.doAuth' is undefined)"`

Comment: That's incorrect. The OP does not pass `mapDispatchToProps` to the `connect` function. Also, he does get values inside `doAuth` but they're not as expected.

Comment: Could you please do a `console.log` on both `this.state.email` and `this.state.password` before passing them to `doAuth` and show me the outputs? @KishanBharda

Comment: @Mezbaメ you are right. Something goes wrong on passing value using `this.state.email` and `this.state.password`. Because whenever I printing `this.state.email` using alert it displays `[object object]` and If I stringify it, it gives me error `json.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures react native`. If I just pass simple string in `doAuth` instead of `this.state.email` and `this.state.password` it works. Can you help me to found solution ?

Comment: How are you setting the values of `email` and `password`? Edit your question and show some more information about them. @KishanBharda

Comment: You are using `onChange={...}`, i think it should be `onChangeText={...}`. @KishanBharda

Comment: Yes @Mezbaメ It is. I solved it.  Thank you  very very mush for helping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195276/discussion-between-mezba--and-kishan-bharda).

Answer (score 0):

When you're passing your function to `mapDispatchToProps` - well, you're mapping it to the props of your component. You have two options:

1. Don't pass nothing in `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Login);
```

and import `doAuth` function:

```
import doAuth from "doAuth"
```

Then you'll be able to have this working:

```
this.props.dispatch(doAuth(.....))
```

2. Pass `mapDispatchToProps`, and call it directly:

```
this.props.doAuth(....)
```

**Now onto** what seems to be your actual problem - If you're getting `[Object Object]` as `email`, it seems that you're passing an object as a parameter. Try logging `this.state.email`:

```
onPress={() => {
console.log(this.state.email)
this.props.dispatch(doAuth(this.state.email, this.state.password))
}}
```

Comment: Your code uses both methods instead of only one. You have `mapDispatchToProps` without even calling it in `connect`. My answer aims to show you how to properly use each method. Moreover, the last part of the answer refers to your actual problem - `doAuth` does indeed get the parameters, just not the ones you expect. You'd have to log the data you send as parameters to understand what is being passed.

Answer (score -1):

You already have the reducer mapped in ‘mapDispatchToProps’

[image]

Anything you define here will be available as a prop to you, so you can call the doAuth as a OnClick for the login button with

```
// code
onClick = (event) => props.doAuth( username, password)
```

But the dispatch call is wrong, you should be using the event name to dispatch (event name was defined in the reduced switch case)
[image]